# Difference between prepend() and prependTo()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't understand the difference between prepend() and prependTo(). can somebody help me understanding the difference.

Comment: have you read the docs?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/prepend/ The .prepend() and .prependTo() methods perform the same task. The major difference is in the syntax—specifically, in the placement of the content and target. With .prepend(), the selector expression preceding the method is the container into which the content is inserted. With .prependTo(), on the other hand, the content precedes the method, either as a selector expression or as markup created on the fly, and it is inserted into the target container.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's really just for chaining.

```
x.prependTo(y)
```

Will prepend `x` to `y` and return the original collection `x`.

```
y.prepend(x)
```

will also prepend `x` to `y` but will return the original collection `y`.

Answer (score 5):

As per the jQuery documentation for [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

> The `.prepend()` and [`.prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) methods perform the same task. The major difference is in the syntax—specifically, in the placement of the content and target. With `.prepend()`, the selector expression preceding the method is the container into which the content is inserted. With `.prependTo()`, on the other hand, the content precedes the method, either as a selector expression or as markup created on the fly, and it is inserted into the target container.

---

Some examples:

### `prepend` example 1

```
<div id="a">
    <p>a</p>
</div>
<div id="b">
    <p>b</p>
</div>
<script>
    $('#a').prepend('#b');
</script>
```

results in*:

```
<div id="a">
    #b
    <p>a</p>
</div>
<div id="b">
    <p>b</p>
</div>
```

this is because `prepend` treats strings as HTML content rather than selectors

### `prepend` example 2

```
<div id="a">
    <p>a</p>
</div>
<div id="b">
    <p>b</p>
</div>
<script>
    $('#a').prepend($('#b'));
</script>
```

results in:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        <p>b</p>
    </div>
    <p>a</p>
</div>
```

### `prependTo` example 3

```
<div id="a">
    <p>a</p>
</div>
<div id="b">
    <p>b</p>
</div>
<script>
    $('#a').prependTo('#b');
</script>
```

results in*:

```
<div id="b">
    <div id="a">
        <p>a</p>
    </div>
    <p>b</p>
</div>
```

<sub>* whitespace will be wrong in these examples for purposes of making the code readable</sub>

Comment: This is the **_best_** of all the other explanations. Concrete examples, with simple code snippets and their output. Covers 3 Major Use Cases which clarify what each function does. Concise, Clear & Simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Copied directly from the docs](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/)

> The .prepend() and .prependTo() methods perform the same task. The
>   major difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of
>   the content and target. With .prepend(), the selector expression
>   preceding the method is the container into which the content is
>   inserted. With .prependTo(), on the other hand, the content precedes
>   the method, either as a selector expression or as markup created on
>   the fly, and it is inserted into the target container.

Which basically says

```
ElementWhereIWantToAppendTo.prepend(This Is The Content That Is Added)
ElementIWantToAdd.prependTo(This Is Where I add The Content)
```